# Cannot Set NSMutableSet as Value for PFObject Key in Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, nsset

Whenever run the below code in my IOS app, it just magically stops running when I make a NSMutableSet a value for a PFFobject Key (line marked with "TROUBLE" below). If I put a break point, the computer just doesn't get to the next break point. I even added a column in my Parse dashboard, where "peopleWhoFavorited" is an Object type, the problem still occurs. Why? Code:

```
BOOL POSTING; //prevents repitious saving when user presses button multiple times.
-(void)post {

if (!(self.data==nil) && ![self.postField.text isEqualToString:@""] && !POSTING && ![self.postField.textColor isEqual:[UIColor grayColor]])   { //hackey with that grey color, but oh well.
    POSTING=YES;
    PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"data" data:self.data];
    [file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            PFObject *post = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"post"];
            [post setObject:@(0) forKey:@"voteScore"];
            [post setObject:@(0) forKey:@"numTimesReported"];
            [post setObject:@[] forKey:@"whoReported"];
            [post setObject:@[] forKey:@"comments"];

            //And now, the favorited sets and upvote and downvote sets...
            NSMutableSet * favoritedSet=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
            [post setObject:favoritedSet forKey:@"peopleWhoFavorited"]; "TROUBLE" //magical stopping point
            NSMutableSet * peopleWhoUpVoted=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
            //[post setObject:peopleWhoUpVoted forKey:@"peopleWhoUpVoted"];
            NSMutableSet * peopleWhoDownVoted=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
            //[post setObject:peopleWhoDownVoted forKey:@"peopleWhoDownVoted"];
            //
            //And a set for the people who report the post.
            NSMutableSet * peopleWhoReported=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
            //[post setObject:peopleWhoReported forKey:@"peopleWhoReported"];
            //
            [post setObject:self.postField.text forKey:@"postName"];
            [post setObject:self.dataTypeString forKey:@"postType"]; //either a movie or an image
            [post setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"dateMade"]; //hackey, equivalent of createdAt to avoid weird behaivor
            [post setObject:file forKey:@"data"];
            NSString * deviceIDString=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
            [post setObject:deviceIDString forKey:@"deviceThatPosted"];

            [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    // set the location of the post.

                    [post setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"location"];

                    //save the post in the background
                    [post saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                        if (succeeded) {
                            NSLog(@"Saved.");
                            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                                NSLog(@"Posted and Dismiss completed");
                            }];
                            POSTING=NO;
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"%@", error);
                            POSTING=NO;
                        }
                    }];
                } else{
                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                    POSTING=NO;

                }
            }];


        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            POSTING=NO;
        }
    }];

}
```

}

Comment: Why a set? Parse (JSON) supports arrays

Comment: Well, a set is a convenient way to avoid duplicates.

Comment: It was my understanding that Parse supports general "Objects" like NSMutableDictionaries and so forth, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: What does 'stops running' mean - does it freeze or crash? If it freezes, does the app's memory usage continue to rise or not

Comment: No it literally stops with no notice. Never gets to the next line. Doesn't inifinite loop before it. The execution just "dissapears." I have seen this behaivor before with Parse, once when there a bug pulling the geopoint location. Parse seems to have particularly sensitive error weaknesses.